# Hash set in Perl

Tags: perl, data-structures, hash, set

Consider the following code:

```
$inFilesToCopy{$filename} = $filename;
```

I have a hash table where both the key and value are the name of a file. I would like to avoid using extra memory and not store the filename twice.

Is there a set object in Perl?

Comment: Why don't you just use an array?

Comment: Because later I want list two folder and copy only unique files from one folder to another.

Comment: Storing the string as both the key and the value does not use extra memory.

Comment: A hash key of `'$_'` is probably not what you want. Single quotes will not do variable substitution so `'$_'` is literally the string `'$_'` and not the value of $_.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Set::Object](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Set::Object) works as
you'd expect:

```
use Set::Object qw(set);

my $files = set();
$files->insert($file);
my @files = $files->members();
```

You can also do set math:

```
my $a = set();
$a->insert(...);

my $b = set();
$b->insert(...);

my $only_in_a = $a - $b;
copy_to_b($only_in_a->members);
```

Answer (score 8):

You might consider doing:

```
$inFilesToCopy{$_} = 1;
```

and then you can do tests like this:

```
if($inFilesToCopy{$filename}) { ... }
```

you can also use 'keys %inFilesToCopy' to get the list of files.